# Testing class method using Sequel and Rspec

Tags: ruby, class, rspec, sequel

How do I test the .total method using rspec. The method adds the total of the plus_minus column where player_id is x.

```
class Plus_minus < Sequel::Model
 def self.total(player_id)
   self.where(player_id: player_id).sum(:plus_minus)
 end
end
```

When I do:

```
puts Plus_Minus.total(10)
```

It does work, and puts out the correct value.

The thing I am having trouble with is that the data is coming from the database and its not predictable. With an instance method I can create a predictable object to test against.

**EDIT**
This is my test. First I was trying to test it like an instance method. Then upon reading about why it was always failing, I found out class methods are tested different.

```
describe Plus_minus do
  describe '.total' do
    it "returns 1 when plus_minus is 1 and player_id is 10" do
      #various ways of trying to setup the class. 
       expect(Plus_minus.total(10)).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When you say "the data is coming from the database and its not predictable", what do you mean? How is the test environment's database getting it's data, and when, if ever, is it being wiped? Also, what have you tried? Can you show your attempt at writing an rspec test, even if it fails?

Comment: I am beginning to see my problem here. This project I am working on is a hobby/learning one. So I have no test database setup. Or my test database is the only database. Which is full of data.